# Banach-Stone Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

In [Fleming and Jamison's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584880406), Banach first proved a lemma which used directional derivative to identity peak point of functions. Then he used the lemma in the proof of Banach-Stone theorem. After several years, Stone extended the result by loosening the condition compact metric space to compact Hausdorff space. But I can't seem to find any proof by Stone on how he proved the theorem with just only Hausdorff space. If anyone came across the original proof, can share the link here? or anyone still remember the idea, can share it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1937-041-03/S0002-9947-1937-1501905-7/) is the refrence to the original article, see theorem 83.

The main idea of the proof is the following. Let $Z$ be a compact Hausdorff space. For a given $p\in Z$ denote $M_Z(p)=\{f\in C(Z):|f(p)|=\Vert f\Vert\}$. Also denote $\mathcal{M}_Z=\{M_Z(p):p\in Z\}$. Given  $M\in\mathcal{M}_Z$ we can always recover its point $p\in Z$.

Once we have a surjective isometry $V:C(X)\to C(Y)$ we can establish a bijective correspondence between sets $\mathcal{M}_Y$ and $\mathcal{M}_X$. This correspondence gives rise to the bijection $\rho:Y\to X:q\mapsto p$ which turns out to be a homemorphism.

Comment: How do you know theorem 83 given in your link is proved by Stone? Also how is it link to the Banach-Stone Theorem?

Comment: Because this article by M. H. Stone and what is more before Th 83 he said that this proof differs from the similar fact proved by Banach

Comment: In the article, theorem $83$, what does bicompact H-spaces mean? Also, the author defined (I guess) separable bicompact H-spaces as compact metric spaces. Then what about compact Hausdorff spaces?

Comment: Bicompact is deprecated name for compact. In early twentie's compact meant sequentially compact. H-space is a abbreviation of Hausdorff.

Comment: When the author claims that $\|g\|=\sum_{v=1}^{n}{\|f_v\|}$ by inferring the inequalities in pg $470$, why we have $\sum_{v=1}^{n}{|f_v({\tau})|}=g(\tau)$?

Comment: since $a\operatorname{sign}(a)=|a|$ for all $a$, then $g(\tau)=\sum_{v=1}^n f_v(\tau)\operatorname{sign}(f_v(\tau))=\sum_{v=1}^n|f_v(\tau)|$

Comment: Again on page $470$, first sentence 'We can now show that the closed sets ...'. How do we know the set is closed?

Comment: this set is closed as preimage of one point (hence closed) set $\{\Vert f^*\Vert\}\subset\mathbb{R}$ under continuous map $e: \Re^* \to\mathbb{R}:f^*\mapsto |f^*(\tau^*)|$

Comment: Can you elaborate further? I don't understand.

Comment: Do you understand that $e$ is continuous?

Comment: No, I don't understand why $e$ is continuous

Comment: If $f_n^*$ converges to $f^*$ in $\Re^*$ (i.e. in $\sup$ norm), then, it converges pointwise (in paticular at point $\tau^*$). This is equivalent to write that $f_n^*\underset{\Re^*}{\to} f^*\implies e(f_n^*)\to e(f^*)$. So $e$ is continuous Is that clear?

Comment: Okay. Then what does this continuity tell us about the closeness of the set?

Comment: This very basic fact from toplogy that preimage under continuous map of closed set is again closed.

Comment: I think the domain of your map is not correct. Isn't the domain consist of elements $\tau^{*}$ such that $\|f^{*}\|=|f^{*}(\tau^{*})|$?

Comment: @Idonknow, yes you are right., but the argument remains the same.

Comment: I still don't understand why $e$ is continuous. Perhaps you can explain in details?

Comment: Can we still use limit to prove continuity? Because the domain now is not metric space, so we cannot use any distance notion (which includes limit).

Comment: you can use nets

Answer (score 4):

In [here](http://www.eweb.unex.es/eweb/extracta/Vol-17-3/17J3Mari.pdf), the following article of Stone (1937) is referred:

Stone, M.H., Applications of the theory of boolean rings to General Topology, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc., 41 (1937), 375 – 481.

Comment: You beat me to this! Anyway I'll post my answer :)

Comment: ahahah! Norbert, I can be quicker, but surely you're wiser than me ;)

Comment: @Federico: Actually I had read the article before you provided it  in your answer but I didn't find any stone proof on the Banach-Stone Theorem.

Comment: @Idonknow Dear Idonknow, I agree with Norbert' comment to his answer. Maybe you found the statement slightly different from actual formulation because that of Stone is a generalization of the Banach' theorem, but Theorem 83 is what you're looking for. Since Stone doesn't provide any reference (and since he wrote this article in 1937, 5 years after Banach), it is natural to suppose that the proof is by him. Moreover, as the article I linked proves, Theorem 83 is surely the reason why we call it Banach-Stone theorem now. :)