# Prove a set is closed using continuous function

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Suppose $U$ is an isometry isomorphism from $C(Q)$ to $C(K)$ where $C(Q)$ is the Banach space which contains all real value continuous function defined on $Q$ and its norm is the sup-norm, i.e. $\|f\|_{\infty}=\sup\{|f(a)|:a \in Q\}$

Define $Q$ and $K$ to be compact Hausdorff spaces.

Suppose $A =\{ t \in K:|(Uf)(t)|=\|Uf\|\}$. Prove that $A$ is closed in $K$.

This question is from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603966/banach-stone-theorem/608342?noredirect=1#comment1295315_608342), whereby I still don't understand the explanation given.
Can anyone explain why the set is closed in $K$?

Remark: Define a function $e:K\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $e(t)=|(Uf)(t)|$. Note that $\{\|Uf\| \}\subset \mathbb{R}$ is closed. If $e$ is continuous, then we have $A=e^{-1}(\{\|Uf\|\})$ is also closed. Now my question is, why $e$ is continuous?

Comment: What is $f$ in the definition of the set $A$? A fixed function in $C(Q)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your setting correctly (see comment above), then $e$ is just a concatenation of the two continuous functions
\begin{align*}
|\cdot| &: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, \\
U \, f &: K \to \mathbb{R}.
\end{align*}
Hence, $e$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

By the (inverse) triangle inequality,

$$|e(t)-e(s)| = \big||(Uf)(t)|-|(Uf)(s)|\big| \leq |(Uf)(t)-(Uf)(s)|.$$

for ans $s,t \in K$. As $Uf \in C(K)$, this inequality implies the continuity of $e$.