# Linear onto isometry.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $K$ and $L$ be two compact set and $T$ is an linear onto isometric from $C(K)$ to $C(L)$.
My question is that $T(1)$ is the identity map in $C(L)$, where 1 is the identity map in $C(K)$ . give me some hint.

Comment: Are you asking if $T(1)$ must be the identity map?  By identity do you mean $f(x)=x$?  I think your setup and question is not clear.

Comment: I am asking about$f(x)=1$, for all $ x$ in $X $ .

Comment: $C(K)$ is a ring of continuous functions?

Comment: Actually $C(K)$ is collection of all continuous function. I am consider the linear isometric $T$ considering $C(K)$ as a vector space .

Comment: @user149010 It is [worth to read](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603966/banach-stone-theorem)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the simplest example could be something like this : Let $K = L = [0,1]\sqcup [2,3]$ and let $T : C(K) \to C(L)$ be given by
$$
T(f) = (f\vert_{[0,1]}, -f\vert_{[2,3]})
$$
However, I do think that with sufficiently stringent conditions on $T, K,$ and $L$, the [Banach-Stone theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Stone_theorem) should help you ensure that $T(1) = 1$ (For instance, if $T$ is an algebra isomorphism, this is true, but that is obviously asking for too much)

Comment: OP said that $T$ is linear isometric and **onto** so by Banach-Stne theorem $T(f)=f\circ\phi$ for some homeomorphism $\phi$. In this case we obviously have $T(1)=1$. The Question is how to prove this without appealing to such strong theorem.